# Oracle - Date not like with percentage

Tags: oracle, date

I am writing to you because I need help about a SQL Query with date.

I would like to modify this query :

```
WHERE TABLE.date NOT LIKE to_date('31/12/2013','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

For each 31/12 in each year will be excluded.
Something like : NOT LIKE to_date('31/12/20%%','DD/MM/YYYY')..

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `LIKE` is for string matching. It doesn't make sense for dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the good way is :

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(TABLE.date, 'DD/MM') != '31/12'
```

And if you want excluded 31/12 for each year since 2000 only, it's :

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(TABLE.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') NOT LIKE '31/12/20%'
```